# Is there a method to switch from one page to another?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an application using flutter, I got to display the first page and I created sub pages. 
My problem is that I don't know how to display a second page when you click on an item. example: I created a grid of 8 boxes and each box must display a unique page at the click. i.e. item 1 returns page 1, item 2 returns page 2, item 3 returns page 3... etc.

here is a capture of the first page

[image: flutter]

Comment: Can you add some code. Do maybe it will be clear.

Comment: Have you solved your problem with the code below?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following code example. With the Navigator you can go to the next page and display it.

```
class NavigatorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => nextPage(context, index),
              child: Card(
                ...
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextPage(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page1()));
    } else if (index == 1) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is the [`Navigator`](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation) object. In flutter it's used to navigate the user between screens by having one initial screen and then stacking more on top of it. [This is a good tutorial on the basics](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics).

In general good practise is to use named routes ([tutorial here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)) but you don't need to use named routes to use the Navigator. In your example you can put the following in a `onPressed` argument on each item:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PageTwo()
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

On first Screen, write this code.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SecondScreen()
    );
  },
);
```

You must **import** the Second Screen in First Screen dart file.